# wamp server port forwarding for separate router and modem

Tags: php, android, wamp, port, forward

How do I port forward my wamp server when I have a separate modem (D-link) and router(iBall). I tried to forward port 3306 and 80 on my modem with address of my router.Also did the same on my router Port Forwarding link with my laptops internal IP Address. I want to access my database from html and php files, also the php is usedas back-end from android for database access,

```
Object Not Found

The requested URL '/1.html' was not found on the RomPager server.
Return to last page
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I checked on open port finder and it says the port 3306 is open on my External IP.
And on the browser I accessed my html file as 
http://[my external ip]/1.html

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP's tend to block port 80 by default as this would allow you to host a website on your home connection.

Comment: okay, so  do I need to change my apache's port from 80 to something else?

Comment: You can try that yes, never hurts to try anything

Comment: Sure, I will give a try and will be back .

Comment: Shall I replace ServerName localhost:8510
with ServerName [my external ip]:8510
where 8510 is the new port number

Comment: I am able to access the page from my internal ip address,like,
192.168.2.101:8510/1.html
but now the access with [external IP]:8510/1.html says 
"This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Change ServerName to your external ip too

Comment: You also need to tell WAMPServer that it is allowed to accept connections from external ip addresses. Do `wampmanager -> Put Online`

Comment: I put it online, but now it says, 
"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Hide details
Google Chrome's connection attempt to [External IP] was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured."